# Memory efficient sorting with key

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement a memory efficient Burrows-Wheeler Transform in `Python`.

Given a string text, I create a sorted list of indices(`i`, `j`, ...) of text, where the cyclic string starting at `i` is lexicographically less than the cyclic string starting at `j`.

I want to store the indices of the starting position of cyclic string, since storing all cyclic string takes too much memory: `len(text) * len(text)`

```
>>> text = "hellohowareyou$"
>>> ids = [i for i in range(len(text))]
>>> ids.sort(key=lambda i: text[i:] + text[:i])

>>> print(ids)
[14, 8, 1, 10, 0, 5, 2, 3, 4, 12, 6, 9, 13, 7, 11]

>>> print([text[i:] + text[:i] for i in ids])
['$hellohowareyou', 'areyou$hellohow', 'ellohowareyou$h', 'eyou$hellohowar',
 'hellohowareyou$', 'howareyou$hello', 'llohowareyou$he', 'lohowareyou$hel',
 'ohowareyou$hell', 'ou$hellohowarey', 'owareyou$helloh', 'reyou$hellohowa',
 'u$hellohowareyo', 'wareyou$helloho', 'you$hellohoware']
```

The problem is, that using this code, `python` creates a list of the keys in memory and I run out of memory for large texts. I want `python` to only create the strings at each comparison and then forget about them again to have memory usage of `2 * len(text)`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: General note on the choice of the implementation language - if you want it to be memory efficient then fall-back to C/C++ and expose the API to Python to call.

Comment: The question is not clear enough. Why don't you simply sort the original list and not its indices?

Comment: The more I look at it the more I agree with @ShaharA. Please provide a self-contained snippet + example input data  + expected result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297887/performance-issues-in-burrows-wheeler-in-python

Comment: Thanks @Tanmayjain I implemented the comparator from Tim Peters answer